# iphone html 5 video - how to start from different time

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari, html5-video

What is the correct way to begin playback of a video from a specific time?

Currently, the approach we use is to check at an interval whether it's possible to seek via currentTime and then seek. The problem with this is, when the video fullscreen view pops up, it begins playback from the beginning for up to a second before seeking.

I've tried events such as `onloadmetadata` and `canplay`, but those seem to happen too early.

**Added information**:
It seems the very best I can do is to set a timer that tries to set `currentTime` repeatedly as soon as `play()` is called, however, this is not immediate enough. The video loads from the beginning, and after about a second, depending on the device, jumps. This is a problem for me as it provides an unsatisfactory experience to the user.

It seems like there can be no solution which does better, but I'm trying to see if there is either:
a) something clever/undocumented which I have missed which allows you to either seek before loading or otherwise indicate that the video needs to start not from 00:00 but from an arbitrary point
b) something clever which allows you to hide the video while it's playing and not display it until it has seeked (So you would see a longer delay on the phone before the fullscreen video window pops up, but it would start immediately where I need it to instead of seeking)

Comment: How are you currently checking to see if is possible to seek?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this;

```
var video = document.getElementsById("video");
video.currentTime = starttimeoffset;
```

more Information can be found [on this page dedicated to video time offset howtos](http://blog.gingertech.net/2009/08/19/jumping-to-time-offsets-in-videos/)

Comment: This does not work on iPhone. You don't have access to that sort of stuff before the video is loaded.

Comment: i never said its a finished solution. But that this goes into the onload/ready function is kinda clear. You didn't provide any code, so don't expect to get anything working

Comment: If you feel that there is not enough information, please allow me to clarify. I've added a comment to the question.

Comment: I meant to say I've edited the question to add some more information. There's no code that should be necessary as all I'm asking is whether there is a way to get a video to pop up at the correct time offset in the case of iPhone.

However, I'm not sure what you're getting at with onload/ready. Those are page level events, and the video still won't be loaded on an **iPhone** until you start playing. Again, this is an **iPhone**/Safari question, and I am inquiring about the behaviors and oddities of specifically this system, not general desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For desktop browser Chrome/Safari, you can append #t=starttimeoffsetinseconds to your video src url to make it start from certain position.
For iOS device, the best we can do is to listen for the timeupdated event, and do the seek in there. I guess this is the same as your original approach of using a timer.

-R